# How do I get a Button to hide on amount of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently using this code to track the amount of elements and remove the `.remove`buttons when the variable is on a certain value:

```
if ($('#choose_'+numQ).find('input.r').last().attr('name').slice(6) == 0) {
    $('#choose_'+numQ).find('.removerad').hide();
}
```

When only one of the `class="-items"` elements is present I need the remove button to disappear. If this is not done, it will enable the back-end user to delete this last field that is left and he/she will not be able to add this element again.

I have also tried declaring variable `items` in the event for the remove buttons (like it has been done in the event for the add buttons) and tried applying `.length` in the `if` statement like so:

```
if (items.length == 0)
```

But that did not work. The code-block above does seem to work on another `.group` element in my HTML template which is named `radio_0` in the HTML section of this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F4XFd/3/), but the JQuery event has been excluded to reduce the amount of code for this question.

Also, the events for `newq` and `removeq` have been excluded for reading convenience. I'm not sure how to get a button to hide on the amount of elements. How do I do this in JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
if ($('#choose_'+numQ).find('input.r').last().attr('name').slice(6) == 0) {
```

to

```
if ($('#choose_'+numQ).find('input.r').last("[name $=-items]").length == 0){
```

Comment: you mean .length i guess

Comment: @A.Wolff - Nope, but you got me in the right direction. `$('#checkbox_'+numQ).find('input.checkbox').length == 1` I'll be generous...